# How to use of SQLSTATE '45000' MESSAGE_TEXT in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_self_votes BEFORE INSERT ON votes
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF(new.user_id = (SELECT author_id FROM posts WHERE id=new.post_id)) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot vote for yourself";
      END IF;
    END;
```

Now I want to know, how can I use of that text `you cannot vote for yourself` in PHP?

**Note:** I use PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a try...catch and check for the result of statement execution to print error information like this:

**Stub**

```
create table votes (user_id int);

delimiter //

create trigger prevent_self_votes before insert on votes
for each row
begin
    if (new.user_id = 12) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'You cannot vote for yourself, dude!';
    end if;
end //

delimiter ;
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'test', 'test');
$sql = 'insert into votes values (:user_id)';
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
if ($statement === false) {
    echo 'statement is false';
    exit();
}

try {
    $result = $statement->execute(array(':user_id'=>12));
    if ($result === false) {
        $error = $statement->errorInfo();
        print_r($error);
        echo "$error[2] ... is the error reported by trigger\n";
    }
    else {
        print_r($result);
        echo 'Inserted', "\n";
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**Result**

```
$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => 45000
    [1] => 1644
    [2] => You cannot vote for yourself, dude!
)
You cannot vote for yourself, dude! ... is the error reported by trigger
```

As you notice here, you could use the output of `$statement->errorInfo()[2]` to extract information provided by the trigger.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php says that the first item in the array is SQLSTATE ANSI SQL error code, second item is driver specific error code and third item is driver specific error message.

Answer (score 1):

If your query fails, check what caused the failure Look at the definition of [PDOStatement::errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php).